# How to make the table width fit the text?

Tags: tables, fit

I am trying to make my table fit the text. I tried `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`, but it makes no difference. Your help is appreciated.

The following code:

```
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
    \textsc{Date of Birth:} 30 May 1993 & \textsc{Phone:} +31 649 52**** 
    & \textsc{email:}  \href{mailto:K.***@student.***8.nl}{K.***@student.***8.nl} \\
 \end{tabular}
```

Comment: How do you mean "fit the text"? If it is the left alignment try `{@{}lcl}`. If that is not what you are looking for try to clarify the question. It often helps to give a minimal working example (MWE) that shows the problem.

Comment: By fitting the text I meant no white space between columns.

Comment: This is a single-row `tabular`, which seems unnecessary. Secondly, if you don't want any spaces between the columns, then you don't need columns, really...

Comment: For options, see [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the spacing by the `@` operator (find more on e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). So by `{l@{}c@{}l}` you completely remove the inter column spaces. Probably you want some spaces, and then you can add it as for example `{l@{\ }c@{\ }l}`. In the nelow example I have also added one version where only one column is used. I do not really see the reason for three (as it is given in this example).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l@{}c@{}l}
  \textsc{Date of Birth:} 30 May 1993 
  & \textsc{Phone:} +31 649 52**** 
  & \textsc{email:}  \href{mailto:K.***@student.***8.nl}{K.***@student.***8.nl} \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l@{\ }c@{\ }l}
  \textsc{Date of Birth:} 30 May 1993 
  & \textsc{Phone:} +31 649 52**** 
  & \textsc{email:}  \href{mailto:K.***@student.***8.nl}{K.***@student.***8.nl} \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \textsc{Date of Birth:} 30 May 1993
  \textsc{Phone:} +31 649 52**** 
  \textsc{email:}  \href{mailto:K.***@student.***8.nl}{K.***@student.***8.nl} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]